# if condition inside while loop not working while it is working separately

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Here is the script which works on their own but when I use them together it is not working as it was supposed to. The problem here is the if condition inside while loop was supposed to get value from the database and execute statement depending on condition for value of $watch which will be further used in $rajat. But the while loop is running only 1 time. If I run while loop and if statement seperately then they are working. What might be the problem here. Thank you in advance for any help....

```
 <?php
include_once("php_includes/connect_to_mysqli.php");
// Query the body section for the proper page
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects  WHERE status='1' ORDER BY id DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
$rajat='';
$watch='';
$y=200; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
    $p_title = $row["project_title"];
    $p_details = $row["description"];
    $p_attachment = $row["attachment"];
    $p_skills = $row["skills_req"];
    $p_min = $row["budget_min"];
    $p_max = $row["budget_max"];
    $p_abid = $row["average_bid"];
    $p_bcount = $row["bids"];
    $p_type = $row["type"];
    $p_owner = $row["posted_by"];
    $p_cat = $row["category"];
    $pid = $row["id"];
    $p_posted = $row["posted_date"];
    $p_expire = $row["expire"];


//Find project owner with id=$p_owner
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$p_owner'"; 
$quebry = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quebry)){ 
    $p_own = $row["username"];
    $p_own_con = $row["country"];
    $p_own_avt = $row["avatar"];
}
//Check for watchlist
$sql = "SELECT id FROM watchlist WHERE user_id='$y' AND project_id='$pid'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $watch_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($watch_check < 1) {
        $watch= '<div class="watchhold" id="watchhold'.$pid.'"><div class="watchoff" id="watchoff'.$pid.'"  onclick="addwatch('.$pid .','.$y.',\''.$p_title.'\',\'watchhold'.$pid.'\')"></div><span>Add to Watchlist</span></div>';

    }else{

          $watch='<div class="watchhold" id="watchhold'.$pid.'"><div class="watchon" id="watchon'.$pid.'"></div><span>On Watchlist</span></div>';

        }
//End watchlist

    $rajat .= '<div class="jobBoard">
    <div class="tags"><img src="img/add_banners/feat.png"><img src="img/add_banners/seal.png"><img src="img/add_banners/urgent.png"><img src="img/add_banners/fulltime.png"><img src="img/add_banners/private.png"><img src="img/add_banners/nda.png"></div>
    <div class="proj_info"><div><a href="project_detailss.php?pid='.$pid.'" class="title">'.$p_title.'</a>'.$watch.'</div><div class="project_stats"><span class="bold">Fixed Price:  $'.$p_min.'-$'.$p_max.'</span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted: '.$p_posted.'&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Ends: '.$p_expire.'&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="numproposals-link" id="bubble_40683796" href="project_detailss.php?pid='.$pid.'" onmouseover="projectJs.showAvgBubble(\'40683796\',\'Low\',\'n/a\',\'High\',\'n/a\',\'Avg\',\'n/a\');" onmouseout="projectJs.hideAvgBubble();"><span class="bold">'.$p_bcount.'</span> Proposals</a></div>
    <div class="desc collapsed descFull" id="40683796Desc">
        '.$p_details.'</div><div class="prof">
        <span class="midgrey">Category:</span> <span title="Web Programming">Web Programming</span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="midgrey">Skills:</span>'.$p_skills.'</span></div>
    <div class="prof"><span onmouseover="projectJs.showRatingTooltip(40683796);" onmouseout="projectJs.hideRatingTooltip(40683796);">
        <div class="eol-buyer-rating-small eol-buyer-rating-small-0" id="buyerRating40683796">
</div>| <a style="display:inline-block;" id="buyerRating40683796profurl" class="clientname" href="testing.php?u='.$p_own.'">'.$p_own.'</a>
</span>|&nbsp;&nbsp;<img data-src="/media/images/4.0/flags/in.gif" style="visibility: visible; zoom: 1; opacity: 1;" src="/media/images/4.0/flags/in.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$p_own_con.'</div></div>
</div> ';


}

 mysqli_free_result($query);
?>
```

Comment: How about removing the end bracket `}` of the `while` loop, the end bracket is at the end of your script ..

Comment: Based on the posted code, you've got an extra (unnecessary) curly brace right before //check for watchlist.

Comment: or phrased differently: There is no if-condition  inside your while loop (it consists of three lines only).

Comment: using a while() loop to fetch a single row from a query result smacks of cargo cult programming...

Comment: I'm surprised this runs, should be a syntax error: unexpected }.

Comment: I don't find any unnecessary curly brace... which curly brace are you talking about .. can you please point me there (previously there was some codes missing now I updated the above codes... it was missing first while loop....)

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra curly brace....

```
//Find project owner with id=$p_owner
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$p_owner'"; 
$quebry = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quebry)){ 
    $p_own = $row["username"];
    $p_own_con = $row["country"];
    $p_own_avt = $row["avatar"];

//} <-- this shouldn't be here

//Check for watchlist
$sql = "SELECT id FROM watchlist WHERE user_id='$y' AND project_id='$pid'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $watch_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($watch_check < 1) {
        $watch= '<div class="watchhold" id="watchhold'.$pid.'"><div class="watchoff" id="watchoff'.$pid.'"  onclick="addwatch('.$pid .','.$y.',\''.$p_title.'\',\'watchhold'.$pid.'\')"></div><span>Add to Watchlist</span></div>';

    }else{

          $watch='<div class="watchhold" id="watchhold'.$pid.'"><div class="watchon" id="watchon'.$pid.'"></div><span>On Watchlist</span></div>';

        }
//End watchlist

    $rajat .= '<div class="jobBoard">
    <div class="tags"><img src="img/add_banners/feat.png"><img src="img/add_banners/seal.png"><img src="img/add_banners/urgent.png"><img src="img/add_banners/fulltime.png"><img src="img/add_banners/private.png"><img src="img/add_banners/nda.png"></div>
    <div class="proj_info"><div><a href="project_detailss.php?pid='.$pid.'" class="title">'.$p_title.'</a>'.$watch.'</div><div class="project_stats"><span class="bold">Fixed Price:  $'.$p_min.'-$'.$p_max.'</span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted: '.$p_posted.'&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Ends: '.$p_expire.'&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="numproposals-link" id="bubble_40683796" href="project_detailss.php?pid='.$pid.'" onmouseover="projectJs.showAvgBubble(\'40683796\',\'Low\',\'n/a\',\'High\',\'n/a\',\'Avg\',\'n/a\');" onmouseout="projectJs.hideAvgBubble();"><span class="bold">'.$p_bcount.'</span> Proposals</a></div>
    <div class="desc collapsed descFull" id="40683796Desc">
        '.$p_details.'</div><div class="prof">
        <span class="midgrey">Category:</span> <span title="Web Programming">Web Programming</span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="midgrey">Skills:</span>'.$p_skills.'</span></div>
    <div class="prof"><span onmouseover="projectJs.showRatingTooltip(40683796);" onmouseout="projectJs.hideRatingTooltip(40683796);">
        <div class="eol-buyer-rating-small eol-buyer-rating-small-0" id="buyerRating40683796">
</div>| <a style="display:inline-block;" id="buyerRating40683796profurl" class="clientname" href="testing.php?u='.$p_own.'">'.$p_own.'</a>
</span>|&nbsp;&nbsp;<img data-src="/media/images/4.0/flags/in.gif" style="visibility: visible; zoom: 1; opacity: 1;" src="/media/images/4.0/flags/in.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$p_own_con.'</div></div>
</div> ';


}

 mysqli_free_result($query);
?>
```